# Ansible-Tower ssl: the specified credentials were rejected by the server

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I am getting the following error when using ansible-tower to connect to my windows machine.

I did go use the [ansible tower connecting to windows](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/2.4.5/html/administration/tipsandtricks.html#connecting-to-windows-with-winrm) where they suggested to use the following under `inventories > variables`:

```
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_ssh_port: 5986
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

But when I run the job it still fails, looks like it is still trying to use `ssh` not `winrm` to connect. Below is the out put from my ansible tower job:

```
> ansible-playbook 2.4.1.0   
 config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg  
> configured module search path = [u'/var/lib/awx/.ansible/plugins/modules',
> u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']   ansible python module
> location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible   executable
> location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook   python version = 2.7.5
> (default, May  3 2017, 07:55:04) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat
> 4.8.5-14)] Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file SSH password:  PLAYBOOK: main.yaml
> ************************************************************ 1 plays in main.yaml PLAY [all]
> ********************************************************************* 11:24:35 TASK [Gathering Facts]
> ********************************************************* 11:24:35 fatal: [server_ip]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ssl:
> the specified credentials were rejected by the server", "unreachable":
> true}
```

Am I missing anything? I see mostly people talking about ansible but not tower. I was able to get this working using ansible so I know I can connect to the windows server. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I've googled a lot and finally the below configuration worked for me. I've added ntlm to my config file.

```
ansible_user: user@DOMAIN.COM
ansible_password: password
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_ssh_port: 5986
ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

Comment: Thanks for the info; no need to add `ansible_ssh_port: 5986` btw.

Answer (score 1):

Got this to work following this article thanks to the author [ansible kerberos setup](https://www.virtualtothecore.com/en/configuring-windows-machines-for-ansible/), may help someone else:

1. install krb5-workstation, gcc, krb5-devel, krb5-libs, pip install
   kerberos, pip install requests_kerberos
2. Follow the article to test ansible connectivity to windows first
3. Change the host name under group to FQDN name not ip in tower. If required you can add ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos to variables
4. Relaunch the job.